# Azure Functions with PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying out Azure Functions using PHP.
Getting the request information is not working for me.

I've not been able to find any documentation at all with the information of how to use Azure Functions with PHP code.

According to the only couple of examples, it seems that in order to retrieve the input information you need to first get the content of the `req` variable (or whatever name you assign in the function configuration).
That has the path of the file containing the request information (in theory).

`$input_path = getenv('req');`

So far, if I check the content of it, I get something like this:

`D:\local\Temp\Functions\Binding\e2b6e195-02f7-481b-a279-eef6f82bc7b4\req`

If I check if the file exists it says true, but the file size is 0.

Do anyone knows what to do here? Anyone with an example? Does anyone know where the documentation is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, unfortunately there's pretty limited documentation out there for php as you have discovered.

At present, looking at the code might be the best doc. Here is the [InitializeHttpRequestEnvironmentVariables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/09a06fc0d7c5368650ffd60ed1a3d5ab3121759d/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/ScriptFunctionInvokerBase.cs#L163) function that adds request metadata to the environment for the script languages (node, powershell, php, python).

Important environment variables are:

- `REQ_ORIGINAL_URL`
- `REQ_METHOD`
- `REQ_QUERY`
- `REQ_QUERY_<queryname>`
- `REQ_HEADERS_<headername>`
- `REQ_PARAMS_<paramname>`

I'm assuming you've made a GET request, in which case there is no content (`req` is an empty file), but you will see that these other environment variables contain request data. If you were to make a POST request with a body then `req` would have data.

Answer (score 2):

here is a full example parsing a GET request in PHP with an Azure Function :)

https://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2017/08/parsing-a-get-request-in-php-with-an-azure-function/

snippet from source:

```
<?php 

//retrieve original GET string 
$getReqString = getenv('REQ_QUERY'); 

//remove the ? for the parse_str function 
$getReqString = substr($getReqString,1,strlen($getReqString)); 

//convert the GET string to an array 
$parsedRequest = array(); 
parse_str($getReqString,$parsedRequest); 

//show contents of the new array
print_r($parsedRequest); 

//show the value of a GET variable 
echo $parsedRequest["code"]; 

?>
```

Comment: Link in response is 404.